# How to locate the position of the wiimote in space using data of infrared from the sensor bar

Tags: c, positioning, infrared, wiimote, wii

I am developing a video game on a FPGA board running linux. I want to use the wiimote to control the game. Now I have a sensor bar with multiple infrared sources at both ends, and a wiimote. I want to track the position of the wiimote in space according to the data of the positions of the infrared sources read in from the IR camera. I have searched for the algorithms to do the positioning but couldn't find detailed algorithms. I am also wondering that whether there happened to be some read-to-use library which already have the positioning algorithm implemented so that I don't need to do it myself.

Currently I am manipulating wiimote with libwiimote library. I can get at most four postions of IR sources from the IR camera. How can I compute the position of the wiimote based on these data? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the position of the location that the wiimote is pointing to, or the actual position of the wiimote in space

Comment: @SteveCox Sorry for the ambiguity here. I mean the actual position of the wiimote in space.